# Identifying slowdown in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, web-optimization

I am working on a site right now that is experiencing a slow down in Internet Explorer. More specifically, the page just freezes for around 2 to 3 seconds after loading all of the visible page elements, as if it is still loading something. Normally, I just profile the site in FF or Chrome, but this issue is specific to IE. I tried using the profiler in IE 8, but it is not getting me anywhere. Does anyone have any suggestions for what to use to identify the point of slow down in IE (for instance, something similar to the network profiling available in chrome)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote you tried to use profiler in IE, but did you use [IE Developer Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/11/introducing-the-ie8-developer-tools-jscript-profiler.aspx)? In section *Using the Profiler* in this article there is a screenshot of profiler and *Function* view, but there is also *Call Tree* view you may want to try.

Press *Start profiling*, do the action you want to inspect, press *Stop profiling*, change to *Call tree* view, sort by inclusive time descending, expand most time-expensive option (first), expand next one, go on, and then you should be able to find slow down point.

I was able to find few code fragments in my project which were quite big problem for IE (like making 1,8k RexExp object etc.).

Comment: That's what I initially did using IE Developer Tools. It did help me tweak things a bit, but the hangup itself is still there. In chrome, you can actually see how man ms specific items took to load. I am not entirely sure if it is javascript slowing down, or maybe some kind of background content loading (for example, an image in a hidden div).